# create ajenti in windows

Tags: php, asp.net

my idea is to create a web application which control the windows pc remotely.. currently there is a method in linux for that namely 'ajenti'. i need to create it in the windows, but having no idea about where to start, or which language platform should use for effective working and all. hope your contribution for the success of these academic project that i needed.

a brief idea is as follows.
A pc will have lots of parameters to monitor and control, like memory consumption, cpu usage at real time, hdd space, processes running, policies, device management, services running etc. Idea is to run a web application server in pc and expose these via web so that a user can remotely view and control his pc's setting and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Eugene from Ajenti Project here.

You can contribute to our project by adding Windows support to Ajenti :)

To introduce support for a new platform, you will need to provide required plugin backends, such as service manager backend, package manager backend; also, you will need to adjust config file paths, and make sure that dependency libraries are available and working on Windows.